# javascript simple function won't pass variable through to identify element id

Tags: javascript, function, variables

I can't understand why the following code won't work:

```js
function popups(m) {
  var popup = document.getElementById(m);
  popup.classList.toggle("show");
}
```

```css
.popup {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.popup .popuptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 160px;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 8px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 125%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -80px;
}

.popup .popuptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

.popup .show {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
  animation: fadeIn 1s;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {opacity: 0;}
  to {opacity:1 ;}
}
```

```html
<div class="popup" onclick="popups(myPopup)">Click me to toggle the popup!
  <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">A Simple Popup!</span>
</div>
```

I am pretty sure the error is within the javascript. When I change it to the following then it totally works. So for some reason, it won't pass my *m* variable to identify the element id...

```
function popups() {
  var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
  popup.classList.toggle("show");
}
```

Any good coder out there that can help me, please?

Comment: myPopup is a string and not a variable. Therefore you need to enclose it in quotes to be interpreted as such: `popups('myPopup')`

Comment: You genious, thanks a bunch!